# Question deleted without any comment/motivation

Tags: discussion, migration, deleted-questions

This question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/619212/file-sharing-between-windows-hosts-and-arch-linux-guests

was deleted without any apparent reason.

Since it deals with an important problem I am trying to fix, I wonder if someone could help me understanding  why it was deleted.

If it is offtopic, despite it is a case of an actual (file) Server Fault,  someone might perhaps help me migrating it on superuser or any other better place.

Comment: I asked a few people in chat and noone really understands your deleted question. I'll guess that it was downvoted as per the tooltip for being unclear. If it's as important as you suggest then if the SF community can't help you after a month then perhaps you should seek professional services from somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

From this post: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

**TL;DR** "Tumbleweed" Questions get automatically deleted as of May 2011

Answer (score 5):

It was deleted automatically by the Stack Exchange engine that runs the Server Fault community, because:

- Negative votes
- Very low views
- No interaction from other members (no answers, comments)

I'm surprised it was deleted after just over a month, but they are always tweaking the system based on known patterns. I guess the patterns show that a question with those metrics stands an extremely high chance of never being answered.

Comment: Normally when one downvotes  s/he has to give some explanations (and to me this is a sign that the question is not inherently offtopic or ill-posed).  Anyway, do you know if/how it can be migrated elsewhere (to avoid cross posting)?

Comment: @antonio - There is no such requirement to comment when downvoting.

Comment: Not only that, but suggestions to require a comment on downvotes have been made repeatedly and shot down on various Meta sites.